# Android app don't run on some devices

Tags: android, compatibility, tablet, android-version

I made one app projected for tablets and cellphones, but for some reason that i don't know...some user with galaxy s4/s5 devices can install the app, but some users with the same device can't install. That happens too with tablet with 8'

I already sent pictures for devices with 7' and 10', but for some reason, this time the app painel said that my app was not designed for 7'

in the manifest i put:

```
<supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />
<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />
</compatible-screens>
<uses-feature 
    android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
    android:required="false"
/>
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to exclude any specific screens? it looks like you've attempted to include every screen type here; if that is the case, you should omit the `<compatible-screens>` element entirely.  From the developer website:

> Caution: Normally, you should not use this manifest element. Using this element can dramatically reduce the potential user base for your application, by not allowing users to install your application if they have a device with a screen configuration that you have not listed. You should use it only as a last resort, when the application absolutely does not work with specific screen configurations. Instead of using this element, you should follow the guide to Supporting Multiple Screens to provide scalable support for multiple screens using alternative layouts and bitmaps for different screen sizes and densities.

or check it out [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/compatible-screens-element.html)